# Sql Recursive Query Adding Amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

This is my table table , what i want is to add the child values to its parent till the top , showing the levels as well
meaing , the result return should be , a

[image]

Query Used

```
WITH RecursiveCTE AS (
    -- Anchor member: Select salesmen and their immediate managers
  SELECT coaid,name, parentCOaid
 --,cast(Amount as int)'Amount'
   ,cast(amount as int) amount
   ,1 level
  FROM accounts
  WHERE parentcoaid = 0
  UNION ALL

    ---- Recursive member: Join the CTE with Sales table to get sub-teams
  SELECT s.coaid, s.name
    ,s.ParentCoaid + r.parentcoaid ,cast(s.amount as int) + cast(r.amount as int) 'Amount'
    ,r.level +1
  FROM accounts s
  INNER JOIN RecursiveCTE r ON s.parentcoaid= r.coaid
)

select * from RecursiveCTE
where level = 1
```

result came this

[image]

Comment: You can take rows with MAX level for every parentCoaid, not level=1. ``s.ParentCoaid + r.parentcoaid`` - a dubious place.

Comment: Which database system do you use? Please add a tag to avoid confusion. Also, please share sample input data and the expected output in text form

Comment: using Sql Server 2012

Comment: Please do not paste images of code or data, only paste them as text.

Comment: Noted, Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interesting task.
See example with some data (the data is slightly different from your example).
First, expand all groups thru all levels.
For example, the graph tree (`does not match the test data`)

```
(1)->(2)->(3)          (6)->(7)     (9)
      |                 |
     (4)->(5)          (8)
```

is transformed into ( series - each node with all child nodes)

```
(1)-(2)-(3)-(4)-(5)
(2)-(3)-(4)-(5)
(4)-(5)
(3)
(5)
(6)-(7)-(8)
(7)
(8)
(9)
```

Then group back by group headers (1),(2),(4),(3),(5),(6) ....
Calculate sum for each node with all child nodes.

```
with r as (
  select 0 lvl,coaid,parentCoaid,name,coaid as HeadId,amount
  from accounts
  union all
  select lvl+1,a.coaid,a.parentCoaid,a.name,r.HeadId,a.amount
  from r inner join accounts a on a.parentCoaid=r.coaid
)
--  select * from r order by newParentId,lvl
select HeadId as coaid
     ,max(case when lvl=0 then name end) name
     ,max(case when lvl=0 then parentCoaid end) parentCoaid
     ,sum(amount) amount
     ,count(*) cnt
     ,string_agg(coaid,',') within group(order by coaid) path
from r
group by HeadId
```

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/c85hbiMI)

Output

| coaid | name | parentCoaid | amount | cnt | path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Master 1 | 0 | 24000 | 7 | 1,3,4,5,6,7,9 |
| 2 | Master 2 | 0 | 3000 | 2 | 2,8 |
| 3 | Master 1-3 | 1 | 13000 | 4 | 3,4,5,9 |
| 4 | Master 3-4 | 3 | 8000 | 2 | 4,9 |
| 5 | Master 3-5 | 3 | 5000 | 1 | 5 |
| 6 | Master 1-6 | 1 | 5000 | 1 | 6 |
| 7 | Master 1-6-7 | 1 | 6000 | 1 | 7 |
| 8 | Master 2-8 | 2 | 3000 | 1 | 8 |
| 9 | Master 4-9 | 4 | 3000 | 1 | 9 |
| 10 | Master 10 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 10 |

Test data

```
create table accounts (coaid int, [name] varchar(90),parentCoaid int, amount float);
insert into accounts values
 (1,'Master 1'       ,0,0.0)
,(2,'Master 2'     ,0,0.0)
,(3,'Master 1-3'   ,1,0.0)
,(4,'Master 3-4'   ,3,5000.0)
,(5,'Master 3-5'   ,3,5000.0)
,(6,'Master 1-6'   ,1,5000.0)
,(7,'Master 1-6-7' ,1,6000.0)
,(8,'Master 2-8'   ,2,3000.0)
,(9,'Master 4-9'   ,4,3000.0)
,(10,'Master 10'     ,0,0.0)
;
```

Graph

```
( 1 ) -(3)-(4)      (2)      (10)
 |  \    \    \       \
(6) (7)  (5)  (9)     (8)
```

We can take only nodes with childs and nodes without parents

```
with r as (
  select 0 lvl,coaid,parentCoaid,name,coaid as HeadId,amount
  from accounts a
  where parentCoaid=0 
    or exists(select coaid from accounts a2 where a2.parentcoaid=a.Coaid)
  union all
  select lvl+1,a.coaid,a.parentCoaid,a.name,r.HeadId,a.amount
  from r inner join accounts a on a.parentCoaid=r.coaid
)
select HeadId as coaid
     ,max(case when lvl=0 then name end) name
     ,max(case when lvl=0 then parentCoaid end) parentCoaid
     ,sum(amount) amount
     ,count(*) cnt
     ,string_agg(coaid,',') within group(order by coaid) path
from r
group by HeadId
```

| coaid | name | parentCoaid | amount | cnt | path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Master 1 | 0 | 24000 | 7 | 1,3,4,5,6,7,9 |
| 2 | Master 2 | 0 | 3000 | 2 | 2,8 |
| 3 | Master 1-3 | 1 | 13000 | 4 | 3,4,5,9 |
| 4 | Master 3-4 | 3 | 8000 | 2 | 4,9 |
| 10 | Master 10 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 10 |

Update2:
Recursive subquery result

| lvl | coaid | parentCoaid | name | HeadId | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | Master 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | Master 1-3 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 6 | 1 | Master 1-6 | 1 | 5000 |
| 1 | 7 | 1 | Master 1-6-7 | 1 | 6000 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | Master 3-4 | 1 | 5000 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | Master 3-5 | 1 | 5000 |
| 3 | 9 | 4 | Master 4-9 | 1 | 3000 |
| 0 | 2 | 0 | Master 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 8 | 2 | Master 2-8 | 2 | 3000 |
| 0 | 3 | 1 | Master 1-3 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | Master 3-4 | 3 | 5000 |
| 1 | 5 | 3 | Master 3-5 | 3 | 5000 |
| 2 | 9 | 4 | Master 4-9 | 3 | 3000 |
| 0 | 4 | 3 | Master 3-4 | 4 | 5000 |
| 1 | 9 | 4 | Master 4-9 | 4 | 3000 |
| 0 | 10 | 0 | Master 10 | 10 | 0 |

Comment: How did you get the graphs you used in your explanation? Handmade? Or is there some software that does this? I'd find the latter useful!

Comment: Only Stackoverflow text editor. Handmade)

Comment: I have removed the

 ,string_agg(coaid,',') function , as it had an error , 

The function 'string_agg' may not have a WITHIN GROUP clause.

apart from this , the data returned was good, thanks

Comment: Yes, ``string_agg`` works with SQL Server 2017 and later. Column ``path`` is only for clarity.

Comment: can you guide me , how to view all data of level 1 or level 2